# Why is this type of look common for Japanese websites?

Tags: website-design

I've noticed that a lot of Japanese websites, ranging from a lot of different topics use the same layout and style. The last website I've found is: http://dolittle.eplang.jp/

So why is it common? Is there a certain design aspect that I'm not seeing? (Which could very well be the case since I'm a back-end developer) I haven't seen any English website which uses this kind of look.

EDIT: I'm talking about the dotted border underneath the post title, the abundant usage of lists and the 2001 layout.

Comment: You mean a header, a menu on the left and the main context box on the right? That’s not Japanese, that’s universal. You’re going to have to be more specific about what constitutes this look. I don’t see anything special or out of the (Western) ordinary in the page you’ve linked to. Find a few more examples and spell out what it is that makes you say they have a common look, then you’re much more likely to get some interesting answers.

Comment: I did not mean that, but I get that it's confusing as to what I meant. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewing the source of the page you can find a tag which seems to explain your question:

<meta name="GENERATOR" content="**Quick Homepage Maker** v5.0 rev.1307 PHP.5.4.45" />

This information is in the footer of the page too.

[Quick Homepage Maker](http://www.open-qhm.net/) seems to be a free generator for website (try to read with the [translation](https://translate.google.it/translate?sl=ja&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=it&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.open-qhm.net%2F&edit-text=&act=url) of Google Translator).

In my opinion the templates (or themes) of this generator are very similar, like the default ones of Wordpress or Joomla (and others).